# does this promise look correct?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

this seems like it should be delivering data to my scope, but it isn't, is there anything that directly jumps out as wrong with the below code ?

```
angular.module('Lunch.services', [])
  .factory 'LunchMates', ($q, $http) ->
    LunchMates = 

      getLunchMates: () ->
        d = $q.defer(); 
        $http.get('/lunchers').then (response, status) ->
          if response.status == 200
            d.resolve(response.data)
        return d.promise

    return LunchMates


angular.module('Lunch.controllers', [])
  .controller('LunchCtrl', ($scope, LunchMates) ->
    $scope.lunchers = LunchMates.getLunchMates()
  )
```

Comment: what if `response.status` is different than 200? You have to reject promise if status code is not equal to 200...

Comment: you should not  check status code inside then method , then method accepts  two functions one is success function and other is failure function in success one you can resolve the promise and in failure you can fail the promise

Comment: What is it returning. I think in controller the method should be  `LunchMates.getLunchMates().then(function(data) { $scope.lunchers=data;});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code: `$scope.lunchers = LunchMates.getLunchMates()` sets a promise on the scope, it relies on an old deprecated functionality.

As of *version >=1.2*, **promise unwrapping** is deprecated, this is the [breaking commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577):

> This commit disables promise unwrapping and adds
>   $parseProvider.unwrapPromises() getter/setter api that allows developers
>   to turn the feature back on if needed. **Promise unwrapping support will
>   be removed from Angular in the future** and this setting only allows for
>   enabling it during transitional period.
>
> ..........
>
> Previously promises found anywhere in the expression during expression
>   evaluation would evaluate to undefined while unresolved and to the
>   fulfillment value if fulfilled.
>
> ..........
>
> **BREAKING CHANGE**: $parse and templates in general **will no longer
>   automatically unwrap promises**. This feature has been deprecated and
>   if absolutely needed, it can be reenabled during transitional period
>   via `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)` api.

You can still enable it with [**`$parseProvider`**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parseProvider) like so:

```
angular.module('Lunch.controllers', [])
  .config( ($parseProvider) ->
    $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)
    $parseProvider.logPromiseWarnings(false)
  )
```

But it would break in future versions (as mentioned above), so instead do this:

```
angular.module('Lunch.controllers', [])
  .controller( 'LunchCtrl', ($scope, LunchMates) ->
    LunchMates.getLunchMates().then (data)->
      $scope.lunchers = data
  )
```

This issue (among some others) is very common, mostly because lots of tutorials & books that new developers find all over the web, was written before version 1.2 and therefore not up-to-date. Always keep yourself up-to-date with the https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md