# Angular and Leaflet : Looping through a promise object and copying its values

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, leaflet, lodash

In my controller, I have a function executed on ng-init:

```
// Find a list of Messages
$scope.find = function() {
    $scope.messages = Messages.query();
};
```

That's the service behind the query():

```
'use strict';

//Messages service used to communicate Messages REST endpoints
angular.module('messages').factory('Messages', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('messages/:messageId', { messageId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

That's how each messag looks (aka the model):

```
0: Resource
  $$hashKey: "00O"
__v: 0
_id: "546fb196971ba6fd20c8db62"
body: "foobar"
created: "2014-11-21T21:41:42.814Z"
location: Object
  lat: 50.827409075117785
  lng: 4.318828582763672
```

Angular has a $scope.markers object in which we can push markers that have lat and lng properties.

I need to go through the $scope.messages, get all location.lat and location.lng values and put them in $scope.markers._id.lat , $scope.markers._id.lng ..

How can we achieve this? I used angular.forEach without getting anything logged:

```
// Find a list of Messages
$scope.find = function() {
  $scope.messages = Messages.query();
  console.log($scope.messages);
  angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(i, location) {
    console.log($scope.messages[i]);
  });
};
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546136/does-this-promise-look-correct/21547135#21547135

Comment: thanks - but the messages are there.. they display on my view..

Comment: did you try `Messages.query(function(messages){ console.log(messages) })` ?

Comment: yep , this seems to work. ($promise: object, $resolved: true)

Comment: could you show me how to use this way in order to run a forEach in the resolved promise object?

Answer (score 0):

To access the messages from your query you need to do this:

```
var messages = Messages.query(function() {
    console.log(messages);
});
```

If that correctly returns your messages to your console, your query is ok and you could then add them to your $scope.markers object:

```
var messages = Messages.query(function() {
    angular.forEach(messages, function(obj, key) {
        $scope.markers[obj._id] = {
            'lat': obj.location.lat,
            'lng': obj.location.lng
        };
    });
});
```